# How can I invoke a AWS lambda asynchronously and get the result in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aws-lambda, airflow

***Some context***: I am using *apache-airflow-providers-amazon* version **7.4.1**. This allows me to use the [LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/7.4.1/operators/lambda.html#invoke-an-aws-lambda-function) which has parameter called *invocation_type* which can be set to "Event" to invoke the lambda asynchronously.

I understand that since the invocation is asynchronous, it will not return a response immediately. What I would like to know is how to wait on that response? My guess would have been a sensor, however looking at AWS, the function states that are available do not seem to indicate a state of a successful invocation.

Here is my code that executes a dummy "hello world" lambda for testing purposes:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function import LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function import LambdaFunctionStateSensor
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

def print_context(**context):
    data = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'setup__invoke_lambda_function')
    print(data)  # I would like "hello world" here

with DAG(
    'lambda-test',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Runs a lambbda as a test',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=20),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

  invoke_lambda_function = LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
      task_id='setup__invoke_lambda_function',
      function_name="aws-pipeline-lambdas-dev-hello-world",
      invocation_type="Event"
  )

  wait_for_lambda = LambdaFunctionStateSensor(
     task_id='wait__invoke_lambda_function',
     function_name="aws-pipeline-lambdas-dev-hello-world"
  )

  read_lamda_output = PythonOperator(
    task_id=f'Read-Lambda-Output',
    python_callable=print_context,
    provide_context=True,
  )

  invoke_lambda_function >> read_lamda_output
```

I would have guessed to use the [LambdaFunctionSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/7.4.1/operators/lambda.html#wait-on-an-amazon-lambda-function-state) to wait for the state, however I can't seem to find a state to wait on.

Comment: Unrelated, `LambdaFunctionStateSensor` lives in `airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.lambda_function` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state sensor is using for polling the state of the infrastructure of the lambda, not its invocations. You might use it after **creating** a lambda. You'd use it to wait until the lambda was in a state where it could be invoked. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html

If you want to invoke a lambda asynchronously you need to provision some sort of sink for its results (where it will send results once it has produced them). A simple sink might be an SQS queue. You can then setup one DAG to invoke the lambda and another to monitor the queue and use it as a data source which it can then do other things with. In the instance of using an SQS queue you would use the SqsSensor class.

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer... for anything async that has to do with Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If your Lambda is producing s3 file as a result (or can produce)
you can listen to the lambda using S3KeySensor.
This sensor operator is effective from resources perspective (the worker is not consuming resources in the time between the polls of check the S3Key)